# Как создать масив с адресами фото?

Tags: javascript

```html
<img src="" width="300px" height="200px" alt="foto">
<img src="" width="300px" height="200px" alt="foto">
<img src="" width="300px" height="200px" alt="foto">
```

Как создать масив с адресами  фото и прокрутить их в цикле и присвоить их  img src

Comment: если имеется ввиду браузерный яваскрипт - то никак. у него нет доступа к файловой системе

Comment: Если имеется в виду nodejs - то [это тут](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback)

Comment: @Grundy  при чем тут nodejs? почему нельзя создать такой массив?  var images = ['../../image/ foto-1.jpg', '../../image/ foto-2.jpg', '../../image/ foto-3.jpg']; к примеру, мы же не знаем какова у него структура файлов на сервере или я что то не понимаю?

Comment: Mihail Yanenko, напиши развернутый вопрос?

Comment: @Air, притом, что автор не хочет просто создать массив, он хочет создать массив _который содержит **имена** изображений **в определенной папке**_. Следовательно подразумевалось, что этим будет заниматься сам яваскрипт, а не программист каждый раз будет вручную забивать все имена файлов из нужной папки. Возможно я ошибся в этом предположении, но в любом случае, все еще непонятно, что именно хочет получить автор вопроса.

Comment: @Grundy, если честно, я этого не понял из вопроса)))  и впрям  править

Comment: Теперь, судя по новой формулировке вопроса, вы предлагаете нам решить учебное/тестовое задание за вас?

Comment: @Grundy, и все же я был прав))))

Comment: @Air, все равно не понятно :)

Comment: <img src="" alt="">
<img src="" alt="">
<img src="" alt="">
   
     var image = ['http://333v.ru/uploads/00/000a7db0d4c688263a3e8d09e1f5fa93.jpg','http://vip-1gl.ru/vipberrrt/102691443461331_oboyki-20.jpg','http://vip-1gl.ru/vipberrrt/102691443461331_oboyki-20.jpg'];
     var img = document.querySelectorAll('img');
     for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
      img[i].src = image[i]; 
     }

Comment: держи мучаник!!!

Answer (score 3):

У браузерного js нет доступа к файловой системе из соображений безопасности.

У **Node.js** есть модуль [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) для работы с файловой системой. В нём есть два подходящих вам метода: асинхронный [readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) и *обычный* [readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options).